# HP Smart tank 515 not printing a specific Color

Tags: printer, hp

For context, my Smart tank 515 does not print the color yellow. It just happened when I tried Printing a document. I've noticed that my the document came out wrong, so I tried to print a Rainbow Spectrum to see what color was missing, and It was yellow.

I've Check the inside of the printer for any complications within the hardware but couldn't find any. I've Also tried Cleaning the smears & the printhead. But the result is all the same. Should I try replacing the printheads or pump the printhead for the ink yellow.

Comment: Have you checked the ink levels? What does the diagnostic page indicate? Have a similar printer of the same product line, so familiar with that type of printer

Comment: Yeah, the ink levels are above 60%, The Diagnostic Page Prints the colors Blue, Magenta, and black on the test patterns, but the color yellow isn't printing out.

Comment: You can try repeatedly running the printhead cleaning. If that does not improve things, a new printhead (or printer) is the way to go.